# Understanding 'onenterframe' in frame script

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am not able to understand framelevel code and onenterframe code.  I have two frame that has action script code.   I have the below code at keyframes  frame1  and frame2.  when it loops the frame trace message  at frame level and  onenterframe gets printed.   What is the use of onenterframe code.  code can be inserted at frame level. I thought that code at framelevel called once at the first time  when the playhead enters the frame.  When i delete the frame2  and  only have frame1 only frame level trace code executed once.  Not sure how frame level code executed once with one frame  and if i have two frame frame level code executed multiple times.

```
**FRAME1**
    trace("frame level");


    this.onEnterFrame =function()
    {
        trace("calling onenterframe");
    }


**FRAME2**

trace(" second frame level");
this.onEnterFrame =function()
{
    trace("calling second onenterframe");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FRAME CODE**

```
stop();

trace("frame level");

this.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    trace("calling onenterframe");
}
```

Running the above code will display what you expect i.e output `calling onenterframe` multiple times.

Basically, since you do not use **stop** flash keeps looping over the frames and running the frame script.

Using stop() ensures that flash runs the frame script once & stops.

If you add an enter frame event, then that function will be called again and again.

Answer (score 2):

On Enterframe gets called according to your framerate.
If you have 24 Frames per second, the enterframe handler gets called 24 times per second. The framecode gets executed only if the playhead reaches the frame. If you never stop your movieclip from looping, you will be executing the framescript and the onEnterFrame script at the same time.